# How to compare 6 values against each other and determine greatest value

Tags: javascript

I am working on a script that needs to determine which variable has the highest number in it. I have 6 variables, each is passed a value at run time and I need to determine which variable has the highest number in it.

Because of the amount of potential combinations (6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720), a straight comparison is out of the question. How should I go about this?

Comment: The amount of combinations is 6!, not 6^6

Comment: Is it me, or does your "current code" have nothing to do with the question?

Comment: What is `v1`, `locationCount`, `locationName`? Why do you use 6 if-statements for the same body?

Comment: @Minion91: I'm no where near a math whiz :) how many possible combinations could appear with a comparison of 6 variables against each other?

Comment: @Minion91: Thanks for the forumala, I will update my question so others can benefit.

Comment: Also, that is the maximum number of permutations, to compare them all against eachother you need way, way less as a > b and b > c means a > c so you don't have to check a against c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.max(5,10,15,20);` would return 20

Comment: Would this work with variable names as well? i.e. Math.max(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) and have it return, say v3?

Comment: it would return the value of v3, if v3 was the highest value

Comment: Thanks Paul - I will give this one a go.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a temporary variable "max" as you loop through each variable, which will contain the current known maximum at that point in the loop. Compare with that variable for each index.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.max` function. It will return max element.